# Dividing down a VHF signal in a 4046 based PLL loop

Tags: pll, frequency-divider

I've decided to build a a PLL based synthesiser to produce the Local Oscillator(LO) signal for my DIY transceiver.  My aim is to try to use commonly available (preferably inexpensive) parts in what is a mainly educational exercise.

I'm a total newcomer to the world of frequency synthesis and PLLs, but what I've read so far suggests I'm looking at a multi-loop configuration (two in this case) to achieve a step size suitable for SSB (around 10Hz) with a fast lock time.

This question is centered on the course tuning loop with a VCO output frequency of 34.5 MHz to 36 MHz (the VCO is a standard double varactor tuned Hartley).  The reference frequency will be 125 KHz (produced from a 4 MHz crystal divided down by 2^5 using a 4060) and the phase detector will be the venerable 4046.

The output frequency is a challenge as it's tantalizingly just out of range of many commonly available divider ICs (the oft quoted 4059 is one example, but its maximum clock is around 30 MHz).  I figured this might be an issue, so I ordered some difficult (but not impossible) to find [MB501L](https://www.qsl.net/n9zia/mc145158/mb501.pdf) dual-modulus prescaler ICs (which have a useful 10MHz lower limit).

I figure I'll need to divide my 34.5MHz output by 276 to get a 125KHz signal for the phase compare, so that's N=4 and A=20, which I'll handle using a microprocessor (the 530KHz odd divided down signal should pose no issues).  I've glossed over a lot of detail here, but the design of the loop itself isn't really the issue.

What I'd really like to know is, **are there any commonly available alternatives to dividing down the 34/36 MHz signal?**  I know I could simply use a cheap si5351 module and be done with it, but I'm doing this for educational reasons, so I'd like to crawl a little first before I sprint!

Comment: You could use a mixer to bring the 34/36 MHz signal into a more manageable range.

Comment: Great, thanks Peter. Actually, I came across that solution earlier today and it's certainly an option.  The thing is, by the time the synthesizer is complete it'll already have two mixers (course - main/fine) and then I'm planning on using one with a DDS module in the fine loop.  I was hoping that there was a uP I wasn't aware of or an easy and cheap FPGA option.

Comment: Have used a PIC microcontroller as the counter/divider. Its 8-bit TMR0 has an asynchronous prescaler that can accept a 34.5MHz square wave. An additional NAND chip is needed to read the prescaler value (since the PIC itself can't read that particular register). The PIC clock is crystal-controlled, acting as an accurate frequency reference.

Comment: Most modern FPGAs should be able to handle 36MHz; they are available as demonstrator / evaluation kits at a modest price in many cases. See for example https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/news/top-three-FPGA-development-boards-new-designers/

Comment: ADF4110 springs to mind. It needs an oscillator frequency of above 80 MHz but has got the division ratios you appear to require and easily converses with a PIC.

Comment: The Lattice ICE (is that the right name?) FPGAs are small, low power, cheap, and well supported.

Comment: @Andy aka apologies for the late follow-up question, but looking at the datasheet for the ADF4110 it does appear the RF Input Frequency (VCO) has a lower bound of 80MHz.  So, how do I get my target frequency in this case?  I'm guessing I'll need an additional mixer to down-convert, am I right?  Otherwise, this IC looks great.

Comment: Just make an oscillator that runs at circa 100 MHz or use the [ADF4002](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADF4002.pdf). Common collector colpitts is usually easier than Hartley.

Comment: @Andy aka ADF4002 seems like the way to go (and it's cheaper too!) Thanks again, as usual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADF4110 springs to mind. It needs an oscillator frequency of above 80 MHz but has got the division ratios you appear to require and easily converses with a PIC.

> So, how do I get my target frequency in this case? I'm guessing I'll
>   need an additional mixer to down-convert, am I right? Otherwise, this
>   IC looks great.

Just make an oscillator that runs at circa 100 MHz or use the ADF4002. Common collector colpitts is usually easier than Hartley: -

[image]

> @Andy aka ADF4002 seems like the way to go (and it's cheaper too!)
>   Thanks again, as usual.